# S3 static website with CloudFront restricted to specific IP range using custom header

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I would like to deploy to a website to a S3 bucket and use static website hosting.  However, I have some strict security restrictions:

1. HTTPS must be used
2. Access to the website must be restricted to a specific IP range

Here is my plan:

- Use AWS WAF to restrict the IPs that can access the website
- Use CloudFront to leverage HTTPS
- Format the CloudFront distribution to forward a custom header that will act like an access key to S3
- Restrict the S3 bucket security policy to only allow traffic that includes the custom header from CloudFront mentioned above.

Here is a diagram:

[image]

I have one big concern though:  Is forwarding a custom header between CloudFront *really* the best way to do this?  AWS docs say that an Origin Access Identity can't be used for S3 buckets that act as a website (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html).  The custom header seems less secure than an Origin Access Identity and much harder to maintain.  It makes me uncomfortable using a random string as the only security preventing someone from bypassing my CloudFront distribution and directly accessing the S3 bucket.  If a malicious party guesses the

My other option here is to just bite the bullet and move to servers where I have more control over a lot of the security but I would like to leverage the convenience of an S3 website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove the website configuration from your S3 bucket and use Origin Access Identity. The rest of your setup is fine.

You don't need to configure your S3 bucket as a website endpoint because you are not going to serve your content directly via S3. With the Origin Access Identity, your bucket will be available only from CloudFront (unless you add something else in the bucket policy) and this is what you want.

See also https://medium.com/@sanamsoodan/host-a-website-using-aws-cloudfront-origin-access-identity-s3-without-static-website-hosting-43995ae2a9bd

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding what selecting "static website hosting" for an S3 bucket means.  I was under the impression that the website wouldn't work at all if I don't configure static website hosting.  When you select static website hosting, you have to select your index/error pages to make your bucket work as a website.  Your answer suggests that configuring static website hosting does nothing more than make the website publicly available.  I thought things like routing wouldn't work unless I configure as a static website.

Comment: There are other differences when your bucket is configured as a website endpoint (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff). Please note that configuring your bucket as a website endpoint doesn't make it public, only the bucket policy controls this. Basically, you configure website endpoint when you are going to serve your static website directly from S3.

Answer (score 1):

- Using AWS WAF to restrict access to a set of IP seems to be the way to go.
- Using Cloudfront you can serve private content also. The bucket need not be public.
  [Allow access to an Amazon S3 bucket only from a CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3/)
  With this approach you don't need a separate bucket policy for IP address restriction

Comment: These docs say you can't use an Origin Access Identity for S3 buckets configured as static websites: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

**"If you use an Amazon S3 bucket configured as a website endpoint, you must set it up with CloudFront as a custom origin and you can't use the origin access identity feature described in this topic."**

Comment: Is it a must to use static website hosting, if yes can you share the reason also ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any custom header on S3, Only certain headers are allowed e.g: Referer, User-Agent etc.
The best method is to use OAI with S3 Rest API endpoint instead of website endpoint.

However, you can choose alternate methods for website endpoint:
1. Allow CloudFront IP ranges to access S3 bucket.

http://d7uri8nf7uskq.cloudfront.net/tools/list-cloudfront-ips

AND
2. Add Origin customer header such as "Referer: some random value" on CloudFront origin configuration and create bucket policy to allow that specific value in Referer header.